# How can I switch tabs in Tab Bar Controller so that the delegate method is informed of the user switching tabs?

Tags: ios, swift

I've tried `selectedIndex` and `selectedViewController` but they do not call the delegate that adds an animation.

[image: Storyboard]

The tab bar delegate:

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
func animateToTab(toIndex: Int) {
    let tabViewControllers = viewControllers!
    let fromView = selectedViewController!.view
    let toView = tabViewControllers[toIndex].view
    let fromIndex = tabViewControllers.index(of: selectedViewController!)

    guard fromIndex != toIndex else {return}

    fromView?.superview!.addSubview(toView!)

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width;
    let scrollRight = toIndex > fromIndex!;
    let offset = (scrollRight ? screenWidth : -screenWidth)
    toView?.center = CGPoint(x: (fromView?.center.x)! + offset, y: (toView?.center.y)!)

    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {

        fromView?.center = CGPoint(x: (fromView?.center.x)! - offset, y: (fromView?.center.y)!);
        toView?.center   = CGPoint(x: (toView?.center.x)! - offset, y: (toView?.center.y)!);

    }, completion: { finished in

        fromView?.removeFromSuperview()
        self.selectedIndex = toIndex
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    })
}

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    let tabViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers!
    guard let toIndex = tabViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
        return false
    }
    animateToTab(toIndex: toIndex)
    return true
}
}
```

Comment: So as i can see, first view controller and second viewcontroller have the cells that change should change tabbar right ?

Comment: Yes. And the fourth one, after pressing a button on the view controller shows a table view controller and its cells should do the same.

Comment: Tapping on the tab bar items triggers the animation, only the cells do not.

Comment: on each class first second and forth, implement self.tabBarController.delegate = self. and write those redundant delegate methods of tabbar. or create a category of UIViewController+Tabbar and implement once and they will be called everywhere. This is what your really need. In case it helps, i will update my answer :).

Comment: Writing the `animateToTab` functions shows errors as the class is not a UITabBarController. Setting it near UIViewController shows an error: `Multiple inheritance from classes 'UITableViewController' and 'UITabBarController`

Comment: Of course try first without the animation as you obviously need to do some other approach and update the animation, but the cell selection will call the tabbarcontroller delegates.

Comment: I can't try without the animation as the animation is the only thing the delegate does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135326/discussion-between-aragunz-and-user6603599).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the SwipeableTabBarController pod.

`pod 'SwipeableTabBarController'`

in Terminal `pod install` in the project directory

open the .xcworkspace file created

then `import SwipeableTabBarController`

delete the `animateToTab` function and the `shouldSelect viewController`
change the class from `class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate` to `class TabBarViewController: SwipeableTabBarController` and in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setSwipeAnimation(type: SwipeAnimationType.push)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i needed same thing as you some times back.
What i did was Subclass UITabBarController, set my main tabbarcontroller on storyboard to this subclass, and set it as rootViewController on appdelegate, assuming the user was logged in.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
     //This will inform you about the selected tab.
    NSUInteger indexOfTab = [[tabBar items] indexOfObject:item];

}
```

And in Swift:

```
 func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {

       var indexOfTab = tabBar.items.indexOfOBject(item)
    }
```

Comment: I've already set another class for the tab bar controller. I have a table view and when the user presses on a cell I want to show a different view controller from the tab bar.

Comment: You want to switch Tabs of TabBar from a tableView?

Comment: When a cell is tapped I want the selectedIndex to change from 0 to 1 but calling the delegate functions.

Comment: Thats pretty simple (just make sure your Tab Bar Controller Identity Storyboard ID is set to "YourTabBarControllerID" and you need to add "?" at the end of it:

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
}

Comment: Already did that. But it doesn't execute the delegate functions.

Comment: did you do self.tabbarController.delegate = self ?

Comment: But the delegate is set in another class.

Comment: Let's suppose you have 3 tabs and in the first tab you have the controller with tableView in it and when u select cells on that tableview delegate should be informed of the changes happen. That First Controller, should implement self.tabbarController = self and all of needed delegate functions of tabbaController. This is it. The class with Cells should own the delegate of tabbar.

Comment: The problem is that I have multiple table views in separate tabs and all their cells should have the same "destination".

Comment: Can you plz update you question and add some sample images from which i can help u more.

Comment: Sure. Thank you! I'm taking some screenshots and I'll update now.